# Operations between java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to find the fastest way, and less complex way to do some union/exclude/intersection operations over Java SE 8 Streams.

I am doing this:

```
Stream<String> fruitStream = Stream.of("apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange");
Stream<String> fruitStream2 = Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon");

//Trying to create exclude operation
fruitStream.filter(
    item -> !fruitStream2.anyMatch(item2 -> item2.equals(item)))
.forEach(System.out::println);
// Expected result: fruitStream - fruitStream2: ["banana","pear"]
```

I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

If I was able to do this operation, I could develope myself all the rest, union, intersection etc...

So, the 2 points are:

1) What am I doing wrong in this solution to get that Exception?

2) Is there a less complex way to perform operations between 2 streams?

**Note**

I want to use streams to learn about them. Dont want to transform them into arrays or lists

Comment: "Dont want to transform them into arrays or lists" You might not want to, but there's not going to be another solution that doesn't involve storing one stream in a collection.

Comment: You realize varargs implicitly creates an array for you, right?

Comment: If you want to ignore the fact that `Stream.of` does the array creation behind the scenes, you *can* simply use `fruitStream.filter(
    item -> !Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon").anyMatch(item2 -> item2.equals(item)))…`, but of course, a `HashSet` based solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time `item -> !fruitStream2.anyMatch(item2 -> item2.equals(item))` executes, it consumes `fruitStream2`. `fruitStream2` can not be used again to filter the second item in `fruitStream1`.

Rather than using a second stream, why not create a `Set` and use `contains`?

```
Set<String> otherFruits = new HashSet<>(); // Add the fruits.
fruitStream.filter(f -> !otherFruits.contains(f)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or `Set<String> otherFruits = Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon").collect(Collectors.toSet());` to be closer to the question’s code.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong in this solution to get that Exception?

You cannot consume several times the same `Stream` and here you consume `fruitStream2` as many times as you have elements in `fruitStream`

> Is there a less complex way to perform operations between 2 streams?

You could convert the second `Stream` as a `Set`:

```
Stream<String> fruitStream = Stream.of("apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange");
Set<String> fruitSet = Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon")
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

fruitStream.filter(item -> !fruitSet.contains(item)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
banana
pear
```

Answer (score 1):

A Stream is an inside iteration/processing executed only once. That is a very limited area.

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> fruitStream2S = () ->
        Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon");

fruitStream.filter(item -> !fruitStream2s.get().anyMatch(item2 -> item2.equals(item)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of silly and it won't give you great performance, but it does fulfill your requirement of not ([explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274149/operations-between-java-streams#comment65899334_39274149)) creating arrays or lists:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Object() {
        Stream<String> fruitStream = Stream.of("apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange");
        Stream<String> fruitStream2 = Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon");
        {
            fruitStream2.forEach(f -> fruitStream = fruitStream.filter(Predicate.isEqual(f).negate()));
            fruitStream.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    };
}
```

Output:

```
banana
pear
```

**EDIT** A (slightly) more straightforward approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> fruitStream = Stream.of("apple", "banana", "pear", "kiwi", "orange");
    Stream.of("orange", "kiwi", "melon", "apple", "watermelon")
            .map(Predicate::isEqual)
            .reduce(Predicate::or)
            .map(Predicate::negate)
            .map(fruitStream::filter)
            .orElse(fruitStream)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```